# Provide the general solution of the multivariable equation having the second order partial derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The question defines $ u$ as a multivariable function: $ u = u(x,y)$.

Moreover, the question provides the partial derivative of $u$ in respect to $x$ as:

$$\frac{\partial ^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}} = 12xy$$

I am not sure about my final answer, which is:

$u(x,y) = 2x^3y+R(y)x+T(y)$

Is this right?

Comment: The solution you wrote is right: $R(y)$ and $T(y)$ are determined from the supplementary initial/boundary condition you'll need to require on $u(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@DanieleTampieri](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317063/daniele-tampieri) comment's, see bellow a more complete answer.

Since we have:
$$\frac{\partial ^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}} = 12xy$$

Integrating in respect with x leads to:

$$\frac{\partial {u}}{\partial{x}} = 6x^2y  +C_1(y)$$

In order to solve the PDE, we need to integrate in respect to x again:

$$u= 2x^3y  + \int C_1(y)dx + C_2(y) $$

$$u= 2x^3y  + C_1(y)\cdot x + C_2(y) $$

Let $C_1(y)= R(y) $ and  $C_2(y)= T(y) $

The final answer is:

$ u(x,y) = 2x^3y+R(y)x+T(y) $

*QED*